# Rails STI renaming objects type, StandardError - The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, sti

I am trying to run a migration that will rename an objects type. I am using `Ruby 1.9.3-p327` `Rails 3.2.18`.

We have a Scorecards model that has many different types, we have used STI to distinguish between the types. Only one of the types of scorecard was named to abstractly. I renamed the model and then fixed all the relationships that belong with it in the system. only now running the migration to change its type is braking. The Type is is model name.

This is the Migration that i am using. it finds all scorecards with that specific type and then updates their types.

```
class UpdateFscScorecardsToShortTermFinancial < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Scorecard.where(type: 'FinancialGenericAlphaScorecard').each do |scorecard|
      scorecard.update_column(:type, 'FinancialShortTermGenericAlphaScorecard')
    end
  end

  def down
    Scorecard.where(type: 'FinancialShortTermGenericAlphaScorecard').each do |scorecard|
      scorecard.update_column(:type, 'FinancialGenericAlphaScorecard')
    end
  end
end
```

when migrating i get this error.

```
==  UpdateFscScorecardsToShortTermFinancial: migrating ========================
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass:
'FinancialGenericAlphaScorecard'. This error is raised because the column
'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance. Please rename
this column if you didn't intend it to be used for storing the inheritance class or 
overwrite Scorecard.inheritance_column to use another column for that information./Users/Nexus/Work/toolkit/db/migrate/20150518133229_update_fsc_scorecards_to_short_term_financial.rb:3:in `up'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I know that the type column is reserved, but i am not changing the column name, i am just changing the type of a scorecard. What is the best practice around doing this? I can see that it is a risky action changing what is in a type column. all the dependencies work, if i was to create a new `FinancialShortTermGenericAlphaScorecard`, it works fine. only viewing older `FinancialGenericAlphaScorecard` dont work. hence the fact i need to change its type.

Comment: Do you still have `FinancialGenericAlphaScorecard ` model in your models directory ?

Comment: Hi Surya.. yeah i still have it in the directory. eventually i had to do a direct sql query.. This seemed to go around all the rails magic     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("Update scorecards set type = 'FinancialShortTermGenericAlphaScorecard' where type = 'FinancialGenericAlphaScorecard'")